# Truncate text if it's too long but allow it to have two rows

Tags: html, css

What I want to do is if the text doesn't fit in two rows, truncate the rest of the text.

Right now this sample, you see `Lorem Ipsum is simply du...` but what it needs to look like is

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy 
text of the printing and...
```

Display the text in two rows but the rest of the text will be truncated.

How can I do that in css?

```css
body{
  font-family:sans-serif;
}

p{
  background-color:yellow;
  font-size:1.5rem;
  width:300px;
  
  /**Major Properties**/
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

```html
index.html
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `line-clamp` attribute is what you need: [Examples](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-clamp/)

> ```
> .line-clamp {
>     display: -webkit-box;
>     -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
>     -webkit-box-orient: vertical;  
>     overflow: hidden;
> }
> ```